# Desktop calendar to keep News and Updates

Tags: desktop-environments, calendar, google-calendar

Need to keep my tasks,events,To-do and especially keep that days latest news in the corresponding date.

please suggest me a good one.

Comment: RTM for tasks.You can create chrome web app for it. You can even sync it with GTG(buggy).For calendar events Evolution is goo one. It has evolution-data-server backend. You can sync it with anything using [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/). For standalone calendar you can try california in Trusty.. <br/> For daily news use twitter. Just follow the channels you like. Or Even you can create your own channel using [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) & follow that channel.Use birdy or polly or friends-app as desktop client for twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `calendar-indicator` - a tool to display your Google Calendar events on the Ubuntu / Unity panel.

You can manage events or add a new calendar all together. It syncs with your google calendar.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calendar-indicator
```

[image]

Comment: Really useful .. But my requirement is, i have to update todays important news into the same calendar. And the calendar should be in my desktop

Comment: To add an event or news, just click the icon and select 'Add new event'. You will be able to choose the date and time of the event. To see the full calendar, click on the icon and select 'Show calendar'. It will display all your events categorized per month. Also the indicator shows the next ten events.